# Express suddenly doesn't include any middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I've been using Node.js and Express for a while perfectly fine for a web application, and suddenly today I keep getting errors about how "Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately"

This is happening because I upgraded npm to 4.0.2 and there is a link in the error dialog documenting how to install and use the new middleware.

```
Error: Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
at Function.get (/Users/Grayson/max_performance_survey_report_v1.5/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:99:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Grayson/max_performance_survey_report_v1.5/server.js:27:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

Edit: I understand how to run with the new versions of express, and how to install the new middleware. I think it would be useful to put down on record how exactly to revert back to the old version of express/npm so that people can if they want to.

Comment: Possible duplicate, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550819/error-most-middleware-like-bodyparser-is-no-longer-bundled-with-express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either add the missing middleware to package.json - you even got a URL in your error message where you can find more info:

- https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware

Or alternatively you can use an older version of Express in your package.json if it works fine for you.

Take a look at the package.json file from one of my projects on GitHub:

https://github.com/rsp/node-express-static-example/blob/master/package.json

It includes:

```
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.14.0"
}
```

You can set some exact version there:

```
"dependencies": {
  "express": "2.0.0"
}
```

and `npm install` would only try to download that specific version. Just find out what was the last version that your application is compatible with and set it there.

Using Travis plus Greenkeeper could help you a lot with testing your code with various versions of your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Did you just upgrade Node? Anyways you should stick to a newer version of Nodejs as they have done some security upgrades and all sorts of helpful stuff.

Express wants you to include the body-parser seperately:

In console:

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

In code:

```
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());                        

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: I did just upgrade npm to 4.0.2. I am pretty much just frustrated that somehow this caused express to update and also mad that the new express doesn't bundle all the middleware it should. I understand it is probably better for versioning, but inconvenient and code-breaking

Comment: Yeah I gotcha. But with all these things there is a reason behind it. They also showed deprecated messages for a long time and it has been at least 2 years since they made this change. I totally get your frustration though.