# most middleware (like favicon) is no longer bundled with express and must be installed separately

Tags: node.js, express

I have tried to solve it by installing serve favicon  to my app direction
like (C:\Users\I am\Backup\Work node install serve-favicon)and got the same mistake.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i7sx.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550819/error-most-middleware-like-bodyparser-is-no-longer-bundled-with-express
There are some good answers there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include any source code so it's hard to guess how it looks like. In order to use the serve-favicon module you need to install it with:

```
npm install serve-favicon --save
```

and use it in your app with something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
```

See the docs:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-favicon